# jQuery tabs hover action AND click through to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I need to create a menu where hovering on a link reveals a div, but then you can click on the link to go to another page. I don't see a way to do this with jQuery tabs, but maybe I'm missing something. Sorry I don't have any code sample... I'm trying to figure out which direction to go. I've also looked at easytabs (http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/), but that does not seem to provide for this either.

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you provide a code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in a standard jQuery UI Tabs plugin. A little note to a code below: jQuery UI Tabs require that anchors to tabs need to have a tab ID as their `href` attribute. So the loop at the beginning iterates through every `a` element in a tabs navigation to move an url to a data attribute. This way the links will work without JavaScript too.

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPZxGj (google.com and stackoverflow.com can't be run in iframes, so only the last page - jquery.com will show up)

JavaScript:

```
$("#tabs ul li a").each(function(index){
  $(this).data("url", $(this).attr("href"));
  $(this).attr("href", "#tabs-" + (index+1));
});

$( "#tabs" ).tabs({});

$("#tabs ul li a").mouseenter(function(){
  $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", $(this).parent().index());
});

$("#tabs ul li a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  window.location = $(this).data("url");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
      <li><a href="http://google.com">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Proin dolor</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://jquery.com">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```